# Resources was deprecated in API level 25

Tags: android, android-resources, deprecated

[Resources was deprecated in API level 25](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html), How can I modify it now?

```
public Resources getResources(Resources resources) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        Configuration config = resources.getConfiguration();
        Locale locale = LanguageSetting.getLanguage(activity);
        config.setLocale(locale);
        DisplayMetrics metrics = resources.getDisplayMetrics();
        return new Resources(activity.getAssets(), metrics, config);
    } else {
        return resources;
    }
}
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kg1rO.png)

Comment: `createConfigurationContext(config).getResources()` ?

Comment: @Selvin `return new Resources(activity.getAssets(), metrics, config);` How should I change this line of code? Thank you.

Comment: return context.createConfigurationContext(config)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the condition that checks if the device android OS is less than `N`. Here: `if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {`. 
That warning and the deprecation line should disappear.

Your code should now look like this:

```
public Resources getResources(Resources resources) {
        Configuration config = resources.getConfiguration();
        Locale locale = LanguageSetting.getLanguage(activity);
        config.setLocale(locale);
        DisplayMetrics metrics = resources.getDisplayMetrics();
        return new Resources(getActivity().getAssets(), metrics, config);

}`
```

Comment: Cool. Please upvote and approve it as the right answer. @tcqq

Comment: I don't see the reason why people needs to downvote this answer. It solves the OP problem.

Comment: `new Resources(getActivity().getAssets(), metrics, config);` deprecated